# How to put the stack trace error in a logger

Tags: java, exception, logging

I need to put the stack trace from exeception in a log, so I do:

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

try{
    ..
}catch(NumberFormatException number_format){
    logger.error(number_format.exception.getStackTrace().toString());
}
```

But it doesn't work because it print me `Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@775a19fe` .Anyone can help me?

Comment: Which logging libraries are you using? Usually, you only need to pass the exception instance, i.e. `logger.error(number_format);` or `logger.error("some message", number_format);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log a stracktrace with a logger, use the overloaded method of the logger that suits to :

```
Logger.error(String msg, Throwable t);
```

Slf4j, Log4j, LogBack, common-logging... all of these distinguish `Logger.error(String msg)` to log an error message and    `Logger.error(String msg, Throwable t)` to log both an error message and the stracktrace of a `Throwable`.

So write something like :

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

try{
    ..
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    logger.error("issue in ...", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getStackTrace()` returns `StackTraceElement[]` for which the `toString()` function is not overridden so you get what you have in the `java.lang.Object` class:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

That's why you get this message. You should use the `getMessage()` function of the `Exception` class instead.

If you want the stacktrace message, you can get it like so:

`Arrays.stream(e.getStackTrace()).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))` and then output it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on your logging library, but usually you do the following:

```
logger.error("Something went wrong", exception);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Commons Lang library can provide a readable stack trace from a given exception, specifically [ExceptionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace-java.lang.Throwable-).

```
try {
    ..
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
}
```